# Unable to set TimeSpan based parameter on an Azure Service Bus subscription filter using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus library

Tags: .net-core, azureservicebus, .net-standard, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

Using the older "Windows.Azure.ServiceBus" library, I am able to setup a SqlFilter that takes as its parameters a TimeSpan, but when I try the same using the "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" library it fails with the following error:

> Object is not of supported type: TimeSpan. Only following types are
>   supported through HTTP: string,int,long,bool,double,DateTime

What I am trying to do:

1. I want to have 2 subscriptions on my topic (highPriority, normalPriority)
2. Messages have a user property called "StartDate"
3. If StartDate <= 1 day, then it should go to highPriority subscription, else it should go to normalPriority. [i.e (StartDate - sys.EnqueuedDateTimeUtc) <= 24 hours].

Code that works (when using the older .net-framework Windows.Azure.ServiceBus package):

```
SqlFilter highMessagesFilter =
       new SqlFilter("(StartDate-sys.EnqueuedTimeUtc) <= @TimeSpanImmediateWindow");
highMessagesFilter.Parameters.Add("@TimeSpanImmediateWindow", TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

var subscription = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString,topicName, subName1);
subscription.RemoveRule(RuleDescription.DefaultRuleName);
subscription.AddRule(new RuleDescription()
{
    Name = RuleDescription.DefaultRuleName,
    Filter = highMessagesFilter,
    Action = new SqlRuleAction("set priorityCalc = (StartDate-sys.EnqueuedTimeUtc)")
});
```

Where as, this code (using: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus) doesnt work:

```
var filter = new SqlFilter("(StartDate-sys.EnqueuedTimeUtc) <= @TimeSpanHoursImmediateWindow");
filter.Parameters.Add("@TimeSpanHoursImmediateWindow",TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

var ruleDescription = new RuleDescription
{
    Filter = filter,
    Action = new SqlRuleAction(@"
        SET HighPriority = TRUE;
        SET Window = StartDate - sys.EnqueuedTimeUtc
        "),
    Name = RuleDescription.DefaultRuleName,

};

await managementClient.UpdateRuleAsync(topicPath,subscriptionName,ruleDescription);
```

The above code throws the following error:

> Object is not of supported type: TimeSpan. Only following types are
>   supported through HTTP: string,int,long,bool,double,DateTime

If instead of managementClient.UpdateRuleAsync, I try using the following code:

```
var subClient = new SubscriptionClient(connectionString, topicPath, subscriptionName);

await subClient.RemoveRuleAsync(RuleDescription.DefaultRuleName);
await subClient.AddRuleAsync(ruleDescription);
```

It fails, with the following error (ServiceBusException):

> Message   The service was unable to process the request; please retry
>   the operation. For more information on exception types and proper
>   exception handling, please refer to
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101

The microsoft link is to a list of exceptions, and FilterException, but its not!

Here is the stack trace of the 2nd exception:

> at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpSubscriptionClient.OnAddRuleAsync(RuleDescription
>   description) in
>   C:\source\azure-service-bus-dotnet\src\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\Amqp\AmqpSubscriptionClient.cs:line
>   132    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.SubscriptionClient.AddRuleAsync(RuleDescription
>   description) in
>   C:\source\azure-service-bus-dotnet\src\Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus\SubscriptionClient.cs:line
>   499    at UserQuery.Main() in
>   C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\LINQPad6_quhgasgl\niqvie\LINQPadQuery.cs:line
>   82

So my questions are:

1. Can I use TimeSpan parameters using .net standard library? or will I have to use the older .net framework library if I wanted to use TimeSpans.
2. Is there a better way to implement what I am trying to do, a way that would work with the newer .net standard library? (FYI: I thought about sending the calculation as the parameter (decimal) and then the parameter would be a double, instead of a TimeSpan). And in fact, thats what I might end up doing.

Comment: Created an issue for the SDK team: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/6629

Answer (score 1):

If the library is throwing an exception stating that `TimeSpan` is not a supported type, then it's pretty much what you have. Note that the .NET Standard client has two implementations, the `ManagementClient` and some operations via entity clients, such as subscription client. The latter is implemented using AMQP. `ManagementClient` is entirely based on HTTP. While it would be ideal to use the AMQP implementation, it's incomplete. I would recommend relying on the `ManagementClient`. This is likely the reason why modifying rules using a subscription client is throwing an exception.

Regarding a better way - your idea sounds right. As long as it's not a type that the new client doesn't accept. Also, you can raise an issue with the library team at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues if you'd like to know the reason why `TimeSpan` is no longer supported.